# can't use pressKey() to trigger function key

Tags: testing, e2e-testing, testcafe

I want to use pressKey() to trigger the F1 or other function key.However,the [pressKey](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402693/reference/test-api/testcontroller/presskey) seems like don't have this ability to finish what I want.

I see someone report the same question [here](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/1887),and in it,one of the solution they gave is like:

```
const pressF5 = ClientFunction(() => {

    var event = new KeyboardEvent('keydown', { key: 'F5' });
    document.dispatchEvent(event)
});

await pressF5();
```

(I have modified it to F5)

I've try this,the `pressF5` work(I don't actually know if it work or not,cause it didn't gave error) but it didn't refresh the page.It just gave me test pass message.Did I use it wrong or is there anyway to trigger the function key?

Thanks in advance if anyone can help!

Edit 10/18
I have something like this:

```
import  {Selector} from 'testcafe';
import  {ClientFunction} from 'testcafe';
fixture`KEY FN`
  .page`https://en.key-test.ru/`

const pressF2 = ClientFunction (() => {
  const event1 = new KeyboardEvent('keydown', { code: 'F2' });
  document.dispatchEvent(event1)
})
const pressF3 = ClientFunction (() => {
  const event1 = new KeyboardEvent('keydown', { code: 'F3' });
  document.dispatchEvent(event1 )
})
test('KEY_FN', async t => {

  await t
    .maximizeWindow()
    .wait(3000)
  await t .eval(() => location.reload(true))
  await t .wait(3000)
  await pressF2()
  await t .wait(3000)
  await pressF3()
  await t
    .wait(3000)
});
```

the site is use on testing which key you press.And the below code works as I think,it detect I press `F2` and `F3`

I do press the key with testcafe,but how to manage to let the site have like if I press `F1`,it show the specific function(for example,if you press `F1` on google,it will pop out a help support page)

Comment: The workaround you provided will not fire the browser events you expect (F1 - help, F5 - reload, F12 - dev tools). Also, testing of these features is outside the scope of testing a web application. That is why they have not yet been implemented in TestCafe.
However, if you provide a specific usage scenario that you want to implement, perhaps, I can help you find a way to do this.

Comment: Hi Ilya Afanasenko!I edit some info in my question,hope this can help solving my problem,and thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned earlier, system events like help calls or DevTools are not part of a web application and therefore are not built into TestCafe. However, some of them you can imitate. So, you've already used a function that is equivalent to `F5` reload:

```js
await t.eval(() => location.reload(true));
```

If you want to call up help, then, in Chrome, you can use

```js
await t.navigateTo('https://support.google.com/chrome/?p=help&ctx=keyboard');
```